# Numeric Keyboard Overlapping with Backspace Button in Apple TV Hebrew Application On Digit Entry Screen

Tags: ios, swift, tvos, apple-tv, tvos14

We have developed an Apple TV application with a Hebrew (RTL layout) interface. The application utilizes a Swift-based Digit Entry view controller for pin entry. However, we are encountering an issue where the numeric keyboard numbers overlap with the backspace button.[[Number 1 hidden behind backspace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoUvb.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS9ig.jpg)

`class TVDigitEntryViewController : UIViewController`

The problem specifically occurs when the Apple TV language is set to English, while the application language is set to Hebrew with RTL layout. As a result, the number 1 from the numeric keyboard is hidden behind the backspace button, as shown in the attached image.

We are seeking a solution or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and ensure that the numeric keyboard is properly aligned with the backspace button in our Hebrew Apple TV application.

Since We use default AppleTV Digit entry class. I was checking the apple forum for any similar issues. And i tried Keeping the AppleTV lanugage as Hebrew, In that case i don't see this issue.